# calculatings bytes 34 - 37 of bmp

Tags: android, bmp

I am trying to calculate a BMP image and put its bytes manually, every thing is gone well, but about bytes 34-37 which are the pixel size of the BMP, I think I am wrong some where, because I don't get the true values, what I am doing is like this :

```
 width = 68 , height = 19 ;

int pixels = new int[68 * 19] = 1292

//... 17 buffers written

 int row = height;
    int col = width;
    int startPosition = (row - 1) * col;
    int endPosition = row * col;


    while( row > 0 ){
        for(int i = startPosition; i < endPosition; i++ ){

            buffer.put((byte)(pixels[i] & 0x000000FF));
            buffer.put((byte)((pixels[i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
            buffer.put((byte)((pixels[i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));

        }
        if(hasDummy){
            buffer.put(dummyBytesPerRow);
        }
        row--;
        endPosition = startPosition;
        startPosition = startPosition - col;
    }
```

But my output when I am reading the bitmap bytes using this method :

```
 getInt(getBytes(data, 34, 4))



private byte[] getBytes(byte[] data, int start, int length) {
    byte[] temp = new byte[length];
    System.arraycopy(data, start, temp, 0, temp.length);
    return temp;
}

private int getInt(byte[] byteArray) {
    int temp = 0;
    temp |= byteArray[0] & 0x000000ff;
    Log.i("whw", "temp0=" + Integer.toHexString(temp));
    temp |= (byteArray[1] << 8);
    Log.i("whw", "temp1=" + Integer.toHexString(temp));
    temp |= byteArray[2] << 16;
    Log.i("whw", "temp2=" + Integer.toHexString(temp));
    temp |= byteArray[3] << 24;
    Log.i("whw", "temp3=" + Integer.toHexString(temp));
    return temp;
}
```

Returns 3876, while expected 1292.

Is there any thing wrong with my coding?

Comment: Please tag the question with the programming language you are using.

Comment: What class is the object `buffer`? What does `buffer.put()` do?

Comment: buffer is a ByteBuffer